# Enterprise library not logging severity correctly

Tags: logging, enterprise-library, event-log, enterprise-library-5

I have a problem with enterprise library 5. It's writing to the event log all the information I want it to write, however, it is not respecting the severity settings I configure.

My exception handling configuration block looks like this:

```
<exceptionHandlers>
  <add name="Logging Exception Handler"
       type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Logging...,"
       logCategory="General"
       eventId="10000"
       severity="Critical"
       title="My unknown error"
       formatterType="Micros...ExceptionFormatter, Micros...ExceptionHandling"
       priority="0" />
</exceptionHandlers>
```

My event log listener template starts with:

```
Severity: {severity}{newline}
```

The event log entry is logged as "Error", not "Critical", however the message that is actually logged contains the text "Severity: Critical"

Any pointers as to how I can actually log an exception as Critical without having to actually write my own exception handler/formatter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behavior you are seeing is part of the .NET API.

There is no level or severity of Critical in the [`EventLogEntryType` Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlogentrytype.aspx) which is used to log to the EventLog.  [`TraceEventType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.traceeventtype.aspx), which is used by Enterprise Library as well as the .NET tracing infrastructure, does support a Critical severity.

However, inside the `System.Diagnostics.EventLogTraceListener`, which is used to log to the EventLog, a Critical `TraceEventType` is converted to an Error `EventLogEntryType`.

In the Event Viewer there **is** a filter for Critical but it seems that this level is reserved for low level errors.  E.g. kernel related.

Comment: For my purposes, using the levels defined in the Enumeration are good enough for now. Pity it doesn't allow you to do use the stuff they've actually defined out-of-the-box.