# How to create CRITICAL events for Windows Event Viewer?

Tags: c#, windows, events

I searched on stackoverflow for previously asked questions and did not find much that helped.

I'm trying to create a c# app that can create windows events (locally and remotely).  I would like to be able to create Critical event-levels (maybe verbose too?).

Anyways, I've been digging around for a couple days now and can't find an answer.  Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: In the Event Viewer there is a filter for Critical but it seems that this level is reserved for low level errors. E.g. kernel related. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8230601/enterprise-library-not-logging-severity-correctly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to log an Event log in the Critical level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38746495/how-to-log-an-event-log-in-the-critical-level)

Comment: Better target for a duplicate is [Enterprise library not logging severity correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8230601/enterprise-library-not-logging-severity-correctly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line of code will **generate a bluescreen** and a critical event:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("csrss")[0].Kill();
```

Use at own risk :P

Comment: This doesn't write a critical event, it generates something that will generate an event, not the same thing

Comment: If you really want to create a bluescreen (not recommended to do often if you like a working OS) then use the [sysinternals application NotMyFault.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/notmyfault)

Answer (score -2):

```
System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry(...)
```

[msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/fc682h09%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Wrong link?  "Writes an **information** type entry, with the given message text, to the event log."  He doesn't want events with the Information severity level.

Comment: Yup...I did that "basic" search as well...but it only supports error, warning, information, success audit, or failure audit.  No Critical.

Comment: @avip...if you know how, I'd appreciate it if you could post an example